# Copy text from all folds, excluding titles

Tags: cut-copy-paste, folding, register, foldtext

How do I copy all lines from all folds, excluding the fold titles?

Comment: Is `ggyG` not working?

Comment: From another question of you I suspect that you are using `foldmethod=marker`. If that is true maybe could you add that information to the question. It would be good that you tell us what is the marker you are using. I believe it would also be helpful if you could add a short example on input and the corresponding output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'title' you mean the fold summary note that they are not copied by the yank operation.

The following sequence in normal mode will copy the content on the entire buffer:

```
ggyG
```

Or if you prefer a command:

```
:%y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are folding using the `foldmethod` `marker` and your maker is `{{{` then  solution is to:

1. Filter out the `marker` line:

```
:g/\({{{\)\|\(}}}\)/d
```

2. Copy the buffer content

```
:%y
```

3. Undo the filtering

```
:u
```

You can make it in one command:

```
:silent! g/\({{{\)\|\(}}}\)/d | %y | silent! u
```

Comment: @markling, did the solution solves your problem?